# SWAPI request in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to get SWAPI data from 'people' using react. I would ultimately like to retrieve the data and then set the people and create a card from the 10 people on page 1. When I console.log my response I am able to see the object returned. I am trying to set that using response.data.results (should contain people).

```
//full code:

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import Cards from "./components/Card"

function People() {

    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
            .then(res => {
                //console.log(res);
                setPeople(res.data.results)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`Data not received ${err}`)
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className = "container">
            {people.map((name, index) => {
                return <Cards name={name} index={index}/>
            })}
        </div>     
    )
}
```

export default People;

When I console.log swPeople after using setswPeople I am returned an empty array.

Any ideas as to why the set is not giving me an array containing the 10 people on page one?

Comment: Can you post your complete code, for instance the `setswPeople` state hook?

Comment: Updated: it was working but API was taking close to 30 seconds for me to be able to see the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import Cards from "./components/Card"

function People() {

const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
        .then(res => {
            //console.log(res);
            setPeople(res.data.results)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`Data not received ${err}`)
        })
}, [])

return (
    <div className = "container">
        {people.map((name, index) => {
            return <Cards name={name} index={index}/>
        })}
    </div>     
)
}
```

looks like this worked after all but it was taking close to 30s for me to see that info logged in console and I was being impatient

Answer (score 2):

I see it working https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-frhmn

it take time to set the state , if we dont pass the second argument [] to useEffect you will see it is returning data correctly but that will cause the infinite loop , so we avoid that